# Howto start InternetExplorerDriver in PHPUnit tests

Tags: php, internet-explorer, selenium, phpunit

Downloaded InternetExplorerDriver but i don't know how to start it in php tests. I'm using https://github.com/chibimagic/WebDriver-PHP/

Answer (score 5):

1. Download selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar from site
   https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list
2. Download IEDriverServer_Win32_2.31.0.zip from site       https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list, then uncompress
3. Add both downloaded file into one directory, and add this dir to system variable path
4. Add C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer into system variable path
5. open command prompt type

   `java -jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=IEDriverServer.exe selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar`
6. Go back to your webdriver setting and change 'firefox' to 'internet explorer'
7. Then you can start testing in ie, but do not forget change ie's default zooming from 125% to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

**Usage**
See the included SampleTest.php. Start up the Selenium 2 standalone server (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list) and run the test with:

```
phpunit SampleTest.php
```

Make sure phpunit is in your path!

**Tests**
What's code without tests? Run the tests with:

```
phpunit WebDriverSelectorTest.php
phpunit WebDriverXPathTest.php
phpunit WebDriverColorTest.php
```

Comment: Question is about howto run existing PHPUnit tests using [InternetExplorerDriver](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.25.3.zip)

Comment: you can not use this program in a browser, use php CLI (Command Line Interface)

Comment: @atmon3r [SampleTest.php](https://github.com/chibimagic/WebDriver-PHP/blob/master/SampleTest.php) is hard-coded to use Firefox. The question is what does he have to change in that file in order to have it use Internet Explorer instead of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing 'firefox', pass 'internet explorer':

```
$this->setBrowser('internet explorer');
```