# Launch phpunit-selenium2 tests in Chrome and IE

Tags: phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I am created test using this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-selenium-2-with-phpunit/. And all work fine, but I can launch this test only on Firefox. I read a lot of articles about this in internet, but I don't find any solution. I have Windows XP, PHP 5.4.7, PHPUnit 3.7.13 by Sebastian Bergmann. Before running test I launched selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar. There is my test

```
<?php
class Example extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{   protected function setUp()
    {   
    $this->setBrowser("firefox");
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://test.com/');
    }

    public function testogin()
    {
        $this->url('http://test.com/');
        $this->timeouts()->implicitWait(10000);
        $username = $this->byId('user_login');
        $username->value('test.ru');
        $password = $this->byId('user_pass');
        $password->value('test');
        $this->byId('login_btn')->click();
    }
}
?>
```

Please, help me run this test on other browsers. If you need more information, ask me. Thanks

Comment: For IE:
See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982954/howto-start-internetexplorerdriver-in-phpunit-tests/15479565#15479565

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For Chrome:

- Glance through the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)
- Download the [ChromeDrive](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)
- Start Selenium with extra argument: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<version>.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver.exe`
- Now do `$this->setBrowser('chrome');` in your setUp()-method

I have not tried the IE Driver yet, so I cannot do more for you then point to the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver).

Lastly, try and run your tests on all these browsers, you can give an array with all browsers: https://phpunit.de/manual/4.8/en/selenium.html
Again, I haven't tried this one myself yet, so I cannot be more specific then those docs.

Hopefully I have given you enough pointers now... :)

Comment: New URL for Chrome driver download: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Answer (score 6):

For IE:

- Download the [InternetExplorerDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)
- Start Selenium with extra argument:

  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-.jar
     -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver.exe **-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=/path/to/IEDriverServer.exe**
- Now do $this->setBrowser('iexplore'); in your setUp()-method